# How to print numbers in pairs...?

Tags: python, printing, numbers

- This question was already answered, thank you all for replies.

I'm a sort-of beginner in python. I've got a problem: how do I list all the numbers from 1 up to 5 (or the number user inputs), and switch n and n+1.

```
number = int(input("Give a number: "))

if the number is for example, 5, I'd want the output to be like this:

2

1

4

3

5
```

Preferably using while / while True / for / if - sentences, not a function. I coded one where it got til' number 4 and one where it was just a infinite loop... This is probably quite simple, but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for any advice or tips from you guys. Also this is my first time using stackoverflow.com so not sure if I know how to quite work this site yet.

Comment: Could you give a detailed example of the ouput your would like ? Here you do not show the pair your are looking for.

Comment: Your output is not number pairs. Present your desired output in greater detail. Also post what code you have come up with.

Comment: why `5` at last, it shouldn't be `6`?

Comment: @Malo I'm sorry if the question was stated weirdly. I wanted to print the numbers like so in the first post: 2 1 4 3 5. By number pairs I mean that the numbers don't print in order, the PAIRS, like 1, 2 and 3, 4 are turned around/switched, to 2, 1 and 4, 3. Anyway, I already got an answer that answered my question, thank you anyway.

Comment: @pakpe I am sorry if the question was stated weirdly. I wanted to print the numbers like so in the first post: 2 1 4 3 5. By number pairs I mean that the numbers don't print in order, the PAIRS, like 1, 2 and 3, 4 are turned around/switched, to 2, 1 and 4, 3. Sorry I did not post the code I had come up with, because I have kept changing it and it wasn't postable, that's why I asked the question in the first place... Anyway, I already got an answer that answered my question, thank you anyway.

Comment: @AlwaysSunny 5 is the last number because the user input was 5. If the input was 6, the numbers would go: 2 1 4 3 6 5

Comment: You should try to state it more clearly, by telling you want to list all the number from 1 up to 5 (user input), and switch n and n+1, n being an odd number. if you could edit/accept edit so your question is clearer that would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple loop from 1 to N and print +1 and -1 of the number in alternance.  If N is an odd number, the last value breaks the rule so you'll need to make sure to not go beyond N.

```
N     = 5
delta = 1
for n in range(1,N+1):
    if n+delta<=N:  print(n+delta) # print value
    else:           print(N)       # if last value breaks the rule 
    delta = -delta                 # alternating +1, -1

2
1
4
3
5
```

If you want to look into more advanced stuff, it could also be done like this:

```
print(*(min(N,n+1+(-1)**n) for n in range(N)),sep="\n")
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! :) And you understood what I meant, thank you for that, the others didn't get what I meant, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution :

```
N = 5
for i in range(1, N+1, 2):
    if i < N:
        print(i+1)
    print(i)
```